# Moving iPhoto to external drive on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) with 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro, photos.app, memory

I bought a Seagate external HD 500gb with my Mac. Recently started using Photoshop and Lightroom, which take up a ton of space. I was thinking of moving my entire iPhoto to the Seagate to free up space. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about it?

Comment: Did you do a [search](http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=iPhoto+move+external) before posting a new question? If the previously posted answers are not helpful, please explain in your question why so people here can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

iPhoto was built with this sort of flexibility in mind: it is possible and in fact iPhoto makes it quite easy.

1. Find your iPhoto library. You'll most likely find it in your `Pictures` folder. If it's not there, open iPhoto while holding the `option` key, and you should get a window similar to the one below. The path to your library is displayed under the library selection box.

[image: iPhoto library selection window]

2. Move your library to the external hard drive.
3. Open iPhoto with the `option` key pressed to open the library selection window I talked about in Step 1. Hit the `Other Library...` button, and find the library on your external hard drive. Pretty easy!

Protips:

- The last library you opened becomes your "default" library. That's the one iPhoto opens automatically when you don't press `option`. If that library isn't available, say your external HDD is not connected, the library selection window will open automatically and list the libraries it can find.
- I keep a library in my computer, but every year or so, when it gets
  too full, I move it to an external hard disk. You can have as many libraries as you want! Pretty useful if you don't feel like having a single massive package.
- iPhoto supports Apperture libraries, as you can see from my screenshot. d:

Let me know if you have any further questions!